# HLSL: Comparison operator in float assignment

Tags: c, hlsl

I'm reading through HLSL code to try to figure out how it works, and I came across a bit of code that looks like this:

```
float aFloat = someVar > someConstant;
```

Now I'm wondering what in the world a comparison operator is doing in a float assignment statement. I know HLSL is C-like, but I've never tried C, though I intend to give it a shot in the future, so any insight into this statement will help there too.

Comment: The result of the comparison is an integer — either 0 or 1 — so the value assigned to the float will be 0.0 or 1.0.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's what I was thinking. I was just a bit confused as to why they would assign it to a float and not a bool. Now I'm guessing it's just so they don't have to cast it in a later calculation. Thanks for confirming my suspicions. If you put your comment in an answer, I'd gladly mark it as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comment to answer.*</sup>

The result of the comparison is an integer — either 0 or 1 — so the value assigned to the float will be 0.0 or 1.0.

Without more context, it isn't possible to say why they did it like that, but it is reliable and determinate.